# HTML/CSS Footer not sticking to bottom moving on screen resize

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following attempt, trying to make a simple sticky footer.

My problem is the **footer is not sicking to the bottom**, I suspect it might be a css problem.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone can give the following code a scan and provide some advise.

```
    #footer { /* position must be absolute and bottom must be 0 */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
  <footer class="footer" id="footer">
     <div class="footLeft" style="width:75%; float:left;">
     </div>
     <div class="footerRight" style="width:25%; float:right; padding:25px;">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size:20px;">Sign Up</button>
     </div>
    </footer>
```

**The Problem Im having / Output**

[image]

Comment: have you given position relative to the body tag. It will be great if you can share a demo url so that we can ispect. Your footer properties are fine. I guess the problem must be with the relative container

Comment: As you can see the position property is set at `position: absolute` there is no additional wrapper over the footer

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee what does your `body` CSS look like? Have you tried adding `body {min-height: 100vh;}` assuming you want the body to always be at least the height of the viewport?

Comment: @MichaelCoker this is my body css `<body style="background-image:url(imgs/misc/splash.png);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;">` It might be that the image cover is conflicting with the footer sticking to bottom?

Comment: @KiranDash Ill try to setup a fiddle

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee thanks. Then you need to reproduce the problem for us here in your post on SO, because there is nothing inherently wrong with the code you provided, so all we can do is guess. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWoJEM

Comment: @MichaelCoker Ill try to set up a fiddle thank you

Comment: body {
    min-height:100%;/*or 100vh */
    position:relative;
} please try adding these styles to body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following rules to body

```
body {
    min-height:100%;/*or 100vh */
    position:relative;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `min-height` property will make sure that the body at least takes 100% of your viewport height. This way even if you have less content your footer will always stick to the bottom of viewport.

`Position: relative` rule is set so that the footer is positioned absolute relative to the body and not any other wrapper

Comment: Kiran Dash that worked! Would you mind giving an explanation, why I had to set the min-height property on body..?

Comment: sure. I will explain and update the answer. Glad that it helped

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope that helped. If it solves your issue. Please make sure to check it as the correct answer. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this native class to achieve sticky footer in bootstrap--

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using `position:fixed`, without influencing the body css.
In that case the footer would be always at the bottom of the page event if a scrollbar is present

Example

```
   #footer { /* position must be absolute and bottom must be 0 */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmevgct2/1/)